# Discretionary hyphens work in LuaLaTeX in Hindi but not in Sanskrit even though script and font are same

Tags: luatex, babel, hyphenation, devanagari

I am typesetting a book with main language as English and second language as Sanskrit. I am using LuaLaTeX (LuaHBTeX, Version 1.15.1) on MiKTeX (22.10) For long compounds in Sanskrit, I want to hyphenate only at specific word boundaries. For this, I use `\hyphenrules{nohyphenation}` and `\-` (discretionary hyphen)

This is my MWE.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage[main=english]{babel}
\babelprovide[import]{sanskrit}
\babelprovide[import]{hindi}
\babelfont[english]{rm}{Charis SIL}
\babelfont{rm}[Renderer=HarfBuzz,Script=Devanagari]{Shobhika}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\begin{document}
\fontsize{12}{18}\selectfont
\chapter{Test}
\section{Hindi}
\begin{sloppypar}\justifying\hyphenrules{nohyphenation}
\textbf{\foreignlanguage{hindi}{उच्चो नाम शिरःस्थान\-गतस्तारस्वरः, स च दूरस्थाभाषण\-विस्मयोत्तरोत्तर\-संजल्प\-दूराह्वान\-त्रासनाबाधाद्येषु। दीप्तो नाम शिरः\-स्थान\-गतस्तारतरः, स चाक्षेप\-कलह\-विवादामर्ष\-क्रुष्टाधर्षण\-क्रोध\-शौर्य\-दर्प\-तीक्ष्ण\-रूक्षाभिधान\-निर्भर्त्सना\-क्रन्दितादिषु। मन्द्रो नाम उरः\-स्थानगतो निर्वेद\-ग्लानि\-चिन्तौत्सुक्य\-दैन्य\-व्याधि\-क्रीडागाढ\-शस्त्र\-क्षत\-मूर्छा\-मद\-गुह्यार्थ\-वचनादिषु।}}
\end{sloppypar}
\section{Sanskrit}
\begin{sloppypar}\justifying\hyphenrules{nohyphenation}
\textbf{\foreignlanguage{sanskrit}{उच्चो नाम शिरःस्थान\-गतस्तारस्वरः, स च दूरस्थाभाषण\-विस्मयोत्तरोत्तर\-संजल्प\-दूराह्वान\-त्रासनाबाधाद्येषु। दीप्तो नाम शिरः\-स्थान\-गतस्तारतरः, स चाक्षेप\-कलह\-विवादामर्ष\-क्रुष्टाधर्षण\-क्रोध\-शौर्य\-दर्प\-तीक्ष्ण\-रूक्षाभिधान\-निर्भर्त्सना\-क्रन्दितादिषु। मन्द्रो नाम उरः\-स्थानगतो निर्वेद\-ग्लानि\-चिन्तौत्सुक्य\-दैन्य\-व्याधि\-क्रीडागाढ\-शस्त्र\-क्षत\-मूर्छा\-मद\-गुह्यार्थ\-वचनादिषु।}}
\end{sloppypar}
\end{document}
```

The script (Devanagari), font (Shobhika) and content are the same in both Hindi and Snaskrit. However, soft-hyphens work as expected when the language is Hindi (`\foreignlanguage{hindi}`) but not when the language is Sanskrit (`\foreignlanguage{sanskrit}`). This is the output I see

[image]

What am I missing? How do I get discretionary hyphens to work in Sanskrit as they work in Hindi?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The babel settings file for Sanskrit (`babel-sa.ini`) contains the following:

```ini
[identification]
charset = utf8
version = 0.11
date = 2021-04-2430
name.english = Sanskrit
name.babel = sanskrit
name.polyglossia = sanskrit
tag.bcp47 = sa
language.tag.bcp47 = sa
tag.bcp47.likely = sa-Deva-IN
tag.opentype = SAN
script.name = Devanagari
script.tag.bcp47 = Deva
script.tag.opentype = deva
level = 0
encodings = 
derivate = no

;; some content skipped

[typography]
frenchspacing = yes
hyphenrules = sanskrit
lefthyphenmin = 1
righthyphenmin = 3
hyphenchar = 
prehyphenchar = 0
posthyphenchar = 
exhyphenchar = 
preexhyphenchar = 
postexhyphenchar = 
hyphenationmin = 
; The syntax is liable to change in 'other' values
hyphenate.other.locale = "200C "200D
hyphenate.other.script = "0CF1 "0CF2
```

The important part here is `prehyphenchar = 0`, which switches off hyphens.

You can switch it back on by changing this setting to the empty value (instead of `0`), which defaults to a hyphen character `-`.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage[main=english]{babel}
\babelprovide[import,typography/prehyphenchar=]{sanskrit}
\babelprovide[import]{hindi}
\babelfont[english]{rm}{Charis SIL}
\babelfont{rm}[Renderer=HarfBuzz,Script=Devanagari]{Shobhika}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\begin{document}
\fontsize{12}{18}\selectfont
\chapter{Test}
\section{Hindi}
\begin{sloppypar}\justifying\hyphenrules{nohyphenation}
\textbf{\foreignlanguage{hindi}{उच्चो नाम शिरःस्थान\-गतस्तारस्वरः, स च दूरस्थाभाषण\-विस्मयोत्तरोत्तर\-संजल्प\-दूराह्वान\-त्रासनाबाधाद्येषु। दीप्तो नाम शिरः\-स्थान\-गतस्तारतरः, स चाक्षेप\-कलह\-विवादामर्ष\-क्रुष्टाधर्षण\-क्रोध\-शौर्य\-दर्प\-तीक्ष्ण\-रूक्षाभिधान\-निर्भर्त्सना\-क्रन्दितादिषु। मन्द्रो नाम उरः\-स्थानगतो निर्वेद\-ग्लानि\-चिन्तौत्सुक्य\-दैन्य\-व्याधि\-क्रीडागाढ\-शस्त्र\-क्षत\-मूर्छा\-मद\-गुह्यार्थ\-वचनादिषु।}}
\end{sloppypar}
\section{Sanskrit}
\begin{sloppypar}\justifying\hyphenrules{nohyphenation}
\textbf{\foreignlanguage{sanskrit}{उच्चो नाम शिरःस्थान\-गतस्तारस्वरः, स च दूरस्थाभाषण\-विस्मयोत्तरोत्तर\-संजल्प\-दूराह्वान\-त्रासनाबाधाद्येषु। दीप्तो नाम शिरः\-स्थान\-गतस्तारतरः, स चाक्षेप\-कलह\-विवादामर्ष\-क्रुष्टाधर्षण\-क्रोध\-शौर्य\-दर्प\-तीक्ष्ण\-रूक्षाभिधान\-निर्भर्त्सना\-क्रन्दितादिषु। मन्द्रो नाम उरः\-स्थानगतो निर्वेद\-ग्लानि\-चिन्तौत्सुक्य\-दैन्य\-व्याधि\-क्रीडागाढ\-शस्त्र\-क्षत\-मूर्छा\-मद\-गुह्यार्थ\-वचनादिषु।}}
\end{sloppypar}
\end{document}
```

With this setting the outputs of the Hindi and Sanskrit versions are identical.